# EnglishAnalyzer with better stop world filtering?

Tags: lucene, mahout, tf-idf

I'm creating TFIDF vectors using Apache Mahout. I specify EnglishAnalyzer as part of document tokenizing like so:

```
DocumentProcessor.tokenizeDocuments(documentsSequencePath, EnglishAnalyzer.class, tokenizedDocumentsPath, configuration);
```

which gives me the following vector for a document I've called `business.txt`. I was surprised to see useless words in there like `have`, `on`, `i`, `e.g.`. One of my other documents has loads more.

What is the simplest way for me to improve the quality of the terms it's finding? I know EnglishAnalyzer can be passed a stop word list but the constructor gets invoked via reflection so it seems like I can't do that.

Should I write my own Analyzer? I'm a bit confused about how to compose tokenizers, filters etc. Can I reuse EnglishAnalyzer along with my own filters? Subclassing EnglishAnalyzer doesn't seem to be possible this way.

```
# document: tfidf-score term
business.txt: 109 comput
business.txt: 110 us
business.txt: 111 innov
business.txt: 111 profit
business.txt: 112 market
business.txt: 114 technolog
business.txt: 117 revolut
business.txt: 119 on
business.txt: 119 platform
business.txt: 119 strategi
business.txt: 120 logo
business.txt: 121 i
business.txt: 121 pirat
business.txt: 123 econom
business.txt: 127 creation
business.txt: 127 have
business.txt: 128 peopl
business.txt: 128 compani
business.txt: 134 idea
business.txt: 139 luxuri
business.txt: 139 synergi
business.txt: 140 disrupt
business.txt: 140 your
business.txt: 141 piraci
business.txt: 145 product
business.txt: 147 busi
business.txt: 168 funnel
business.txt: 176 you
business.txt: 186 custom
business.txt: 197 e.g
business.txt: 301 brand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a custom stop word set to the [EnglishAnalyzer ctor](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.html#EnglishAnalyzer-org.apache.lucene.analysis.CharArraySet-).  It is typical for this stop word list to be loaded from a file, which is plain text with one stop word per line.  That would look something like this:

```java
String stopFileLocation = "\\path\\to\\my\\stopwords.txt"; 
CharArraySet stopwords = StopwordAnalyzerBase.loadStopwordSet(
        Paths.get(StopFileLocation));
EnglishAnalyzer analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer(stopwords);
```

I don't, right off, see how you are supposed to pass ctor arguments to the Mahout method you've indicated.  I don't really know Mahout.  If you aren't able to, then yes, you could create a custom analyzer by copying `EnglishAnalyzer`, and load your own stopwords there.  Here's an example that loads a custom stop word list from a file, and no stem exclusions (that is, removed the stem exclusion stuff, for brevity's sake).

```java
public final class EnglishAnalyzerCustomStops extends StopwordAnalyzerBase {
  private static String StopFileLocation = "\\path\\to\\my\\stopwords.txt"; 

  public EnglishAnalyzerCustomStops() throws IOException {
    super(StopwordAnalyzerBase.loadStopwordSet(Paths.get(StopFileLocation)));
  }

  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
    final Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer();
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(source);
    result = new EnglishPossessiveFilter(result);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    result = new StopFilter(result, stopwords);
    result = new PorterStemFilter(result);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);
  }

  protected TokenStream normalize(String fieldName, TokenStream in) {
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(in);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the assistance in providing the code that will do the job. I'm a bit surprised there isn't a cleverer way to reuse analyzers without copying and pasting.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat - Analyzers are really pretty simple to put together. You pretty much just need to implement the analysis chain in `createComponents`.  Fairly sure that's why they are marked final.  It doesn't really make much sense to extend them, in general, and if you are implementing a custom analyzer, you really *should* be looking at the tokenizer and filters that are being applied.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I need to start learning how to write my own Analyzer and what each component of it actually does.